# How to get credentials from credstash using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kms, credstash

In node, I used to do it this way

```
const Credstash = require('nodecredstash');

    const credstash = new Credstash({
        table: <table_name>,
        kmsKey: <kms_key>,
      });

      return credstash.getSecret({
        name: <secret_name>,
        context: { access: <secret_name> },
      })
```

I tried same using python package `credstash` as per following code

```
import credstash as cd
secret=cd.getSecret(name=<secret_name>,table=<table_name>,context={ 'access': <secrest_name>},kms={ 'key': <kms_key>})
print('GOT', secret)
```

But giving error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decrypt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.
Missed a `kms` client.

```
import boto3
import credstash as cd
from json import loads

kms = boto3.client('kms')

secret=cd.getSecret(
name=<secret_name>,
table=<table_name>,
context={ 'access': <secret_name>},
kms=kms)
print('GOT', loads(secret))
```